# Understanding Recursion and Multiple Returns

Tags: python, recursion

I'm working my way through the MIT 6.00 class on OpenCourseWare and I'm having a little trouble with the lecture on recursion. I think I understand the basic idea, that you can break some problems down into smaller, repeatable problems. Where I'm having trouble is understanding how this works in the actual code. There is one specific example that I don't quite understand...

```
def toChars(s):
    import string
    s = string.lower(s)
    ans = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in string.lowercase:
            ans = ans + c
    return ans

def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])

def isPalindrome(s):
    """Returns True if s is a palindrome and False otherwise"""
    return isPal(toChars(s))
```

This code is supposed to check if a string is a palindrome or not. I am a little lost on how isPal(s) works. Here's the steps as I'm reading them...

1. Check if s is one character or less, if it is return True.
2. If s has more than one character return a Boolean value (True or False) from the expression comparing the first and last character. So basically check if the first and last letter are the same.
3. AND return the result of the function run again with the first and last letters stripped from the string.

What is confusing me is the `return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])` bit. I'm not sure I understand what it means to both return True/False based on the first expression AND return the function. Honestly I'm not even sure what returning the function actually means, I'm guessing it just runs the function again, but doesn't actually return any value. I also don't understand how this can actually tell if a string is a palindrome or not. Wouldn't it just keep hitting the second part of `return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])` until the string, whether it was a palindrome or not, was reduced to 1 or 0 characters? The only thing I can think of is that returning a false value from `return s[0] == s[-1]` exits the function with a return of false? But I don't feel like that's actually how Python works, at least in my study so far I haven't run into anything saying that returning a False in a function would prevent the second part of the return statement from executing, which would call the function again regardless of whether the first and last letters where the same.

I'm kind of banging my head against the wall at this point, so any insight would be really appreciated!

Comment: `return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])` doesn't return the function. It returns True/False. It's equivalent to `return (s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clarification which can help you understand what's going on: `return ...X and ...Y` means: Compute the value of X. If the value is false, return it, otherwise compute the value of Y, and return it.

More info about the short-circuit, lazy behavior (i.e. not evaluating Y if not needed) of the `and` and `or` operators in Python: https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

So that statement doesn't make the function return two values (X and Y), but one value which is the logical AND of X and Y: it's true iff both X and Y are (evaluated to) true.

Also it's worth distinguishing *function* from *function call*. There can be many active calls to the same function, with different arguments, local variables etc., so their return values can also be different (as soon as they return). When a function calls itself, that's called *recursion*. When a function call returns, execution continues in the caller, which can be the same function (but of course a different, upper-level function call) in case of recursion.

Comment: Thank you! That was definitely the part that was tripping me up. So basically there's an assumed "if statement" there such that if the first expression evaluates to false then the whole thing returns false. That makes much more sense now. Thanks again!

Comment: It's worth clarifying why Y part isn't executed and where same behavior can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the best way is to go step by step with the values for that line that is confusing you.

```
return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
```

Assuming the String you're testing for is "ABCDBA", here is the sequence of calls

```
return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1]) #evaluate to ("A" == "A" and isPal("BCDB")) - need to go deeper
return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1]) #evaluate ("B" == "B" and isPal("CD")) - need to go deeper
return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1]) #returns ("C" == "D")
```

Note that in the last line we didn't evaluate for isPal because of short-circuiting - we know that `False and X` where X can be True or False is always False. Read more about that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

At the last line we're 4 functions deep into `isPal`. Since the last line doesn't require us evaluate for `isPal()` again, we start "rising to the surface" back to the original invocation of `isPal` which was at

```
def isPalindrome(s):
    """Returns True if s is a palindrome and False otherwise"""
    return isPal(toChars(s))
```

Comment: Quick question, how does the "rising to the surface" process work? Does it just take the return value, say False, and return it to its caller which then returns it to its own caller and so on until it gets back to the original call? Or are there still evaluations going on as it moves back through all the calls?

Comment: Exactly - it's returning the result to it's caller, each time isPal() (the "caller"), calls another isPal() (the "callee"), it has to wait for the callee to return before the caller can return. So you have isPal(), waiting for isPal(), waiting for isPal(), waiting for isPal() (and the final one finally begins the return process)

Comment: The rising to the surface concept works because every recursive function call pushes the previous function onto the stack, then with every return, the stack is popped. Hence the origin of the expression "Stack Overflow" - when the stack is too full. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the isPal function on `"heeeeh"` with print statements:

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        print s[0],s[-1]
        return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])

print isPal("heeeeh")
```

You get:

```
h h
e e
e e
True
```

as  each char at index `s[0]` and `s[-1]` are equal through each recursive call as the string is a palindrome.

Running it on `"aeeee"`:

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        print s[0],s[-1]
        return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])

print isPal("aeeeeh")
```

You get :

```
a h
False
```

As as soon as `s[0]` and `s-[1]` are not equal the functions ends and returns `False` as it cannot be a palindrome if the chars are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my explanation, maybe this will help you.

First things first:

```
def toChars(s):
    import string
    s = string.lower(s)
    ans = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in string.lowercase:
            ans = ans + c
    return ans
```

will simply take some text and turn it all to lower case, character by character.

Next is:

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        return True
    else:
        return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
```

To understand this part you ask yourself a question, what is a palindrome and what are ways to know if word or sentence is one.

In this example approach is: palindrome is word or sentence where its characters in same distance from beginning and from the end are the same characters.

So how to check that? Well, first if your word is just one letter or shorter then it's a palindrome.

Then you check if letters at the beginning and the end of your word are the same.
You remember the result as true or false and strip your word from letters you already checked and repeat the process until your word is 1 or less characters long and check if every result of comparison was true.

Example:

```
Foob->foob
f=b? NO, false
```

Example 2:

```
Fbof->fbof
f=f? Yes, true,
bo
b=o? No, false.

true and false = false, so the word is not a palindrome
```

Example 3:

```
Fobof->fobof
f=f? Yes, true,
obo,
o=o? Yes, true
b
len(b) = <=1 ? Yes, true,

true and true and true = true, so the word is a palindrome.
```

Hope it helps, ask if you need more thorough explanation, I'll try to help, no worries, i struggled with recursion at the beginning as well.